# How to use ASP.NET Core Web API to catch the domain user?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, userid

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API to provide the services for the domain users.

The requirement: once the domain user calls the API, it should provide the basic info about the current user. I can get the user info from AD (Active Domain Service) without a problem.

The problem is before I call AD (Active Domain service), I need the domain username. The client-side does not explicitly send its domain username. It needs an API to detect the domain username. The question is (ASP.NET Core Web API) how to detect the domain username of the client?

Comment: I'm afraid not,you needs to get the user info from AD (Active Domain Service).Why you need the domain username before you call AD (Active Domain service)?

Comment: @Yiyi You: Thank Yiyi You. My Web API calls AD to get the detailed user info, like first name, last name, email and so on, and return to the client. Before I call AD, I need to know which domain user calls my API, then I will pass the domain user to AD Services, then the AD Services return the user's data.

Comment: Does `User.Identity` give you what you need?  It's from the ControllerBase class.